# Get MSVC intellisense to show base type

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

A lot of times, I do something like this:

```
template <int> struct CTypeMap    { typedef int  Type; };
template <>    struct CTypeMap<1> { typedef bool Type; };
template <>    struct CTypeMap<2> { typedef char Type; };

CTypeMap<0>::Type q;
```

When I hover over q, it would be nice if intellisense showed me Type as "int", "bool", or "char".  Instead I get "CTypeMap<0>::Type"

Are there any ways to trick intellisense into doing something like this?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 will report `q` as being of type `int` instead of `CTypeMap<0>::Type`.  I don't believe this is possible in Visual Studio 2013.  We made a bunch of improvements here for Visual Studio 2015 (e.g., https://twitter.com/jamesmcnellis/status/505099264553680896).

Comment: Cool,I'm upgrading to 2015 as we speak!  Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to get IntelliSense to show this in Visual Studio 2013.

However, in Visual Studio 2015, IntelliSense will report that `q` is of type `int` instead of `CTypeMap<0>::Type`, which is what you want.  This was one of many small tweaks that were made to the IntelliSense help tooltips for Visual Studio 2015.  (My favorite tweak involves the collapsing of typedefs, e.g. for [`std::vector<std::string>`](https://twitter.com/jamesmcnellis/status/505099264553680896).)